# How do I format a timestamp field from database to dutch locale?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, format

I'm trying to format this timestamp string from database to a dutch locale that looks something like this:

> Maandag 2 juli 2013

I tried this:

```
<?php setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL'); echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y", mktime($vac->geplaatstop)); ?>
```

Where  `$vac->geplaatstop;`  is my field from the database. I used a `timestamp` field for this.

I tried this to see if it worked anyway.

```
<?php setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL'); echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y"); ?>
```

That gives the right format, for today. but I want the time from the database.

How could I do this?

Comment: What format is `$vac->geplaatstop` in?

Comment: timestamp. it's added in the database like: `2013-07-01 09:07:44`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
echo strftime('%A %e %B %Y', strtotime($vac->geplaatstop));
```

The function `mktime()`'s arguments are different time elements, see the documentation here:

[**mktime()** -  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)